# Function does not return printf

Tags: c, printf

when I run this program it prints the question and it gets the answer from the user, but it does not say if it's correct or false. Please help!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void
correct (char str[])
{
    char c1 = "Cristoforo";
    char c2 = "cristoforo";
    char c3 = "CRISTOFORO";
    int conf = strcmp (str, c1);
    int conf1 = strcmp (str, c2);
    int conf2 = strcmp (str, c3);
    if (conf1 == 0 || conf == 0 || conf2 == 0)
    {
        printf ("The answer is correct");
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("The answer is wrong");
    }
}

int
main ()
{
  char s[] = "What's the name of the explorere Colombus?\n";
  char r[100];
  printf ("%s", s);
  gets (r);
  void correct (r);
}
```

Comment: Because you're not calling the function `correct` at all. `void correct(r);` simply declares it, not calling it.

Comment: Look out for compiler warnings - there are other things wrong with the code such as `char c1 = "Cristoforo";` which should be `char c1[] = "Cristoforo";`

Answer (score 0):

`void correct(r)` is declaration and it means - correct is a function that takes r type in arguments and returns void. Just remove `void` to call function. `correct(r)`. And you need to change `char`s to `char *` or `const char*`.

```
    const char *c1 = "Cristoforo";
    const char *c2 = "cristoforo";
    const char *c3 = "CRISTOFORO";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `seg` fault due to incorrect use of `strcmp()`. The second parameter is required to be a `const char *__s2`. So what would be right is:

```
int conf = strcmp(str, "Cristoforo");
int conf1 = strcmp(str, "cristoforo");
int conf2 = strcmp(str, "CRISTOFORO");
```

and also remove `void` when calling `correct(r)`